# Pandas Using Frequencies to Offset Date

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I am trying to build a function in Python where if a user provides an offset frequency such as `1D` `10M` `1Y` then I can provide the date using the offset.

Example if user inputs `1M` along with a date `2021-08-25`

```
pd.Timestamp('2021-08-25') - pd.tseries.frequencies.to_offset('1M')
```

The above code outputs `Timestamp('2021-07-31 00:00:00')` which is not one month prior to the date provided by user. Expected Output `Timestamp('2021-07-25 00:00:00')`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since years and months don't have a fixed frequency you can use the [`pd.offsets.DateOffset`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html) method to deal with calendar additions of years and months, similar to the implementation of `relativedelta`.

Because you'll need to specify both the argument *names* and *values* for this to work, you can change your function to pass a `dict` with the arguments as opposed to just the offset frequency.

```
import pandas as pd

def offset_date(timestamp, offset):
    """
    offset: dict of {'offset frequency': periods}
    """
    return timestamp + pd.offsets.DateOffset(**offset)


timestamp = pd.Timestamp('2021-08-25')

offset_date(timestamp, {'months': 1})
#Timestamp('2021-09-25 00:00:00')

offset_date(timestamp, {'days': 10})
#Timestamp('2021-09-04 00:00:00')

offset_date(timestamp, {'years': -3})
#Timestamp('2018-08-25 00:00:00')
```

Comment: Does `relativedelta` works the same as `pd.offsets.DateOffset`?

Comment: @Lopez the docs suggest it's exactly the same

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `pd.DateOffset`:

```py
>>> pd.Timestamp("2020-08-25") - pd.DateOffset(months=1)
Timestamp('2020-07-25 00:00:00')
```

The `frequencies.to_offset()` returns a `<MonthEnd>` object, hence why you were getting `07-31`:

```py
>>> pd.tseries.frequencies.to_offset("1M")
<MonthEnd>
```